# launch mac re-detection of Phy

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I got a armv9 SOC running a linux kernel version 2.6.30 and I need to deal with a MAC layer that can be connected to multiple PHY devices. I can choose which device is actually connected, at one moment, by setting some GPIOs to enable one. Hence, anytime, there is only one of the PHYs that is materially wired with the ethernet layer (during this moment all the other PHYs present high impedances to the MDIO and the MII/GMII buses and hence have no effects on both).

My question is about how to handle this properly in the linux kernel layers. I have found a lot of different way to do the trick but it's dirty and not handled a beautiful way, thus I fall into ugly workarounds in the PHY/MAC drivers.

I think i should relaunch the MAC layer PHY's 're-detection', like it's done when the MAC module is inserted. When I insert the MAC layer module it causes the actual wired PHY probe and the proper driver is load by the upper MAC layer driver.

Could you advice me on the way to think in where you deal with kernel's layers and in my particular case how I should do the detection routine to be call and where I can locate her in the MAC layer.

Thanks

Comment: Important detail to provide when you're asking a Linux kernel question: what is your architecture?

Comment: Sorry, I have a linux 2.6.30 kernel, my processor is armv9

Comment: @BigOddJob Perhaps one (simple) solution would be to have a separate driver for each MAC/PHY combination and bring the interface up/down depending on which one is available.

Comment: @Peter.L Thanks for your comment. Yes it will work fine , maybe I want to do an overkill development, but I was thinking it would be possible to make the kernel react dynamically when I trigger the I/Os on the fly. If I don't find another solution I will do but it will lead me into things such at least a thread in user-space to monitor the states or to synchronization my I/Os write operation with the interface up/down operations.

Comment: @eepp The board is a custom design board which embeds a SOC with audio/video encoders, decoders.. But my question is relly about the functionnment itself of the net/phy interface of the linux kernel

Comment: I Noticed that the kernel do read every seconds the Phy's status register by using the mdio bus  When I switcht the PHY's this case could be handled in the kernel I think. I would like, for instance, making my modules react to this precise situation an do the early phy's detection/registration jobs. One kind of MAC reinitializing.

Comment: @Peter.L Thanks again for the advice. The only thing I was having to do was that you said. In fact the platform I need to deal with have a particular Phy at one moment. It was not a good Idea to make the user-space not aware of the connection switching and the feature I was wanting to bring (kind of phy hot-plug) was definitely an overkill for my needs. I just do insert my two driver and put the interface up/down when I know the link has change. I thing it was the more readily and obvious thing i was needing to do. Yesterday i was blind, but now I see! Thanks for helping!